# Как сделать, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку появлялся текст, а при повторном нажатии исчезал?

Tags: javascript

Мне надо чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "read review" появлялся текст с классом ".hide-text", а при повторном нажатии исчезал, проблема в том что таких элементов у меня 30+ и как сделать по-человечески я не знаю.

Да, еще очень важный момент, можно на чистом js плз. Так как JQ не используется в проекте.

Код html

```
<article class="game-item">
    <h3 class="game-item__rank">Rank <span class="rank-number">3</span></h3>
    <div class="game-item__image">
        <div class="game-image-description">
            <p itemprop="description" class="hide-text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiatnulla pariatur.
                Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.
            </p>
            <img src="img/game-3.png" alt="game-3">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="game-item__button">read review</button>
 
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Получение всех кнопок
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.game-item__button');
for (let btn of btns) {
    // Добавление событие клика для каждой кнопки
    btn.onclick = () => {
        // Получение элемента с текстом из текущего бока
        const text = btn.parentElement.querySelector('.hide-text');
        // Изменение видимости
        text.style.display = (text.style.display === 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let btns =  document.querySelectorAll(".game-item__button");
btns.forEach(item=>{
    item.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
     let text = e.target.closest('.game-item').querySelector('.hide-text').classList.toggle("active");
     
  }) 
})
```